# Google Login like noi.vn?

Tags: openid, oauth

I Build a module login using google account like http://noi.vn/Home/Default.aspx, I use OAuthBase.cs class, I got secret key consumer key as well, some experience member who worked with this before, please show me the way to do it, or some snippet code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample that you're referring to that logs into Google is *not* using OAuth.  It is using OpenID, which is more appropriate for logins.  Google doesn't support users logging into other web sites using OAuth.

Check out the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net) project for how to accept OpenID at your web site, including from Google Accounts on your ASP.NET web site, assuming you're using ASP.NET.